# Protect entire Word document except for one bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-addins, word-addins

I am working on a Word add-in project that contains a few bookmarks. To update these fields the code unlocks the document with:

```
_document.Unprotect(ref _password);
```

then pulls content from a server and locks with:

```
_document.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, ref _noReset, ref _password, ref _useIrm, ref _enforceStyleLock);
```

To keep a specific bookmark unlocked I have tried using the code:

```
_document.bookmark1.Range.Editors.Add (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
```

Which does not keep bookmark1 unlocked. 
Is there something else I can try to make only one bookmark unlock while the others are locked?

Answer (score 0):

I put continuous section breaks before and after the bookmark I wanted to keep editable. Then, then in my LockDocument() function I put the line:

```
_document.Sections[4].ProtectedForForms = false;
```

so my whole LockDocument function looks like:

```
 public void LockDocument()
    {
         _document.Sections[4].ProtectedForForms = false;

        // Locks the rest of the document
        _document.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, ref _noReset, ref _password, ref _useIrm, ref _enforceStyleLock);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing the previous answer:

The "Editors" approach does not work with Forms protection and form fields. If you were to use content controls instead of form fields then you could use Editors and the "Read-Only" type of protection. Also note that Read-Only protection enables much more Word functionality than forms protection.

Please note that every formfield is also a bookmark: the name you give to the form field is the bookmark name. It's not clear why you need an unprotected bookmark, but in case this information helps...